# Integrating WSO2 API Manager and Hadoop

Tags: wso2

My organization has an existing Hadoop cluster. We are in the process of examining API Management products and would like to determine if there is any existing support in WSO2 API Manager for

1. exposing Hadoop REST services through the API Gateway and
2. Lintegrating security with the API Manager's Identity Server.

A casual google search only returns information on backing WSO2 BAM with Hadoop, which I understand is possible, but is not the focus of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can expose REST services as API via APIManager. What APIManager does is, it routes the requests to the backend service based on some throttling/sla policies.
What kind of security you would like to have in API invocation? 
We do oauth based authentication.